# Angular: How I can check if value is not null or undefined before passing it to the child component

Tags: angular, parent-child, interaction, angular-input

I need to manipulate the data in a child component before I use it in a template. I'm getting `null` in `ngOnInit` child component. How I can achieve this?

**parent.component.html**

```
<child *ngIf="list$"
   [data]="list$ | async">
</child>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
list$: Observable<any[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.list$ = this.store.select(getList);
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() data: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('data', this.data); // null
}
```

Comment: try console logging in AfterViewInit lifecycle hook rather than ngOnInit

Comment: Its returning null as well. It will look if subscribe `list$` in parent component but I dont want to subscribe there. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Just added `async` in ngIf

```
<child *ngIf="(list$ | async) as list"
   [data]="list">
</child>
```